# AWS Cognito with Google Signin fails after 1 hour

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-signin, amazon-cognito

I am facing an issue with Google signin that makes me question that Cognito can work at all in this configuration.

Basically, Google token have a 1 hour lifespan.
This is intended to give you access to the Google API for one hour and then you should renew the token.

The issue is that Cognito uses this token with the same lifespan. So it means that after one hour Cognito Sync stops working (and I have not yet found a way to silently refresh the token or even check it is expired).

What bothers me is that I do not want to access Googke API, I just want to refresh my datasets with AWS Cognito Sync and it would not let me because of the Google token. It does not really make sense.

I do not even want to think about the mess it could be in poor network conditions (token is elapsed and cannot be refreshed because user does not have connectivity... user stuck with an usable app... user very unhappy...).

I am wondering why this has not been implemented with server side token (as in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access).
We would get the auth code from Google and then the Cognito servers would deal with the token itself.

I still hope that I am doing something wrong and that it is flawless, but I have run out of things ti try...

Any hint welcome, thanks in advance

JM

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not have connectivity, Cognito Sync will store your data locally and sync when the network connection is available. This will prevent any loss of data because of network issues.

Regarding Google tokens, yes you have to refresh them and give Cognito a new one when the current AWS credentials on the device expire.

Comment: Actually Rachit, I think it is the AWS credential that expire, not the Google ones... Yet, I am puzzled developers have to handle that for Cognito Sync.

Comment: Rachit, I think I start to understand what is happening...
 So basically we need to query credentialsProvider.getSessionCredentitalsExpiration() before any synchronisation attempt. But then what about dataset.synchronizeOnConnectivity(). The session might not be expired when we call this method, but expired when connectivity is back (might use case is mostly offline). Thanks.

JM

Comment: Nope. I am stuck and it seems I am not the only one (a few similar questions are hoping on the AWS Cognito forum). That does not provide a solution, but at least I am not crazy. I have created a minimal app on Github that exhibit the issue https://github.com/ironbird-software/aws-cognito-sync-issues. You are more than welcome to fix it.

Comment: @jmc34 Did you find any solution to this? I am stuck in a similar situation.

Comment: @user3486992, basically the disapointing thing about Cognito is that it does not manage token refresh with ID providers automatically (as you'd expect it does).

So you have to check the expiration of your Cognito token, and if it is expired, you need to first get a new token from your ID provider and then deal with Cognito to refresh the Cognito token.
I was expecting more automation here, but no dice.

You can check here https://github.com/ironbird-software/aws-cognito-sync-issues where I have put a functioning example.

Ignore the README.md, it was written before I found a solution.