# Why does AWS CognitoSync ListDatasets require IdentityId?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

If a user can only access his or her dataset, why is IdentityId a field which has to be set on this API call ([ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoSync.html#listDatasets-property)). Couldn't the IdentityId be inferred from the AWS credentials? Or if they don't have to match, then technically wouldn't that mean that any malicious user could access that dataset, if he or she had the origin user's Cognito ID? Or does the call to ListDatasets re-validate the Cognito ID against the identity provider's token? In which case, what should I cache in my website as a cookie, so that a user won't have to log in every time?

Right now I am caching the CognitoId, but I am worried that if exposed that data will be compromised (or brute force attack), and if it isn't a security hole, then will I have to have the user re-authenticate against their provider each time they want to sync their data? What is the solution here?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**:
I think what I have found is a caching problem with CognitoSync being used in the web browser and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340510/aws-cognito-with-google-signin-fails-after-1-hour?rq=1) which may point to the same issue.  Here is the auth flow I am expecting:

- Login to Web Federated Auth Provider (OIDC, such as Google) => returns temporary token.
- Use token to get temporary credentials and IdentityId from Cognito.
- Cache *Something*.
- Activate CognitoSync Manager to synchronize.

Some Time Later:

- Using the cached *something*, rerun synchronization.

Problems:

- If I cache the OIDC provider token, I can regenerate the AWS credentials, except it expires after 1 hour.
- If I cache the AWS credentials, I can reissue Sync, except the credentials als expire.
- If I cache the IdentityId I can't synchronize, So what do I cache?

Conclusion:

- If AWS Credentials are needed to issue synchronization call, why does the listDatasets require IdentityId again in the API call, can't AWS CognitoSync reverse lookup the credentials to determine what the IdendityId assigned to those credentials are?
- Does the [cognito sdk](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js) actually work?
- Am I forced to use DynamoDB directly to do synchronization, if I want to avoid the Auth flow every time a user wants to synchronize?
- There is a [Caching Provider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.html) for Android SDK, does something like this not exist for the browser? (Does that even work?)
- [Developer docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html) reference refreshing the token, this can only be done when the current token is still active :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be two issues:

- Cognito validates the AWS Credentials against the IdentityId, so there is no security hole. However it still doesn't make sense for the API to contain that as a parameter, Amazon probably will needed to update that API.
- The problem that you are running into is that identity provider should provide a way to get the necessary access token for each request authorization without requiring the user to grant permissions everytime.  Authorize with the provider and then take the access token (or id_token) and send it Cognito as the Login token for that provider each time you want to synchronize.  You actually don't need to cache anything.
- For Google the request looks like:

```
    var nonce = createNonce();
    setCookie('GoogleAuthNonce', nonce, 1);
    var paramString = $.param({
        response_type:'id_token',
        scope: 'openid', //email, profile',
        client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        nonce: nonce,
        login_hint: 'service_email_address',
        prompt: 'none',
        redirect_uri: 'http://service.com'
    });
    window.location.href = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?${paramString}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite either. Cognito will validate the identity id given against the identity id for which the AWS credentials were created. So, for your concern about spoofing, it would not allow user A to get user B's sync data just by knowing their identity id.

Comment: When does that validation occur,what data should be cached in the browser, and how should it be cached (e.g. cookies, locally, special AWS class)?

Comment: It occurs during the API call at the service level. The SDK should cache most things (including id and credentials) for you, why do you ask? Is it not doing that for you?

Comment: The only thing you should need to manage is the provider token for future calls to get credentials.